# Why do I need to refresh the page to get new data in react express?

Tags: reactjs, express

I have two functions - one adds a product and one gets products.
After adding products, I want to get new products instantly without refreshing the page, but I get it after refreshing only:

```
    const addProduct = _ => {
        fetch(`/api/projects/add?name=${project.name}&owner=${project.owner}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(getProjects())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    const getProjects = _ => {
        fetch('/api/projects')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => setProjects(response.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: I don't think is possible instantly. Anyway I don't think is necessary neither because if server responses 200 you already have the products list locally updated, so why recall server? To check if server stored the new product? But it answered 200 so you already knows.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I don't know how your answer helps me? When the page loads, I am fetching the data from the api. When I add data to the api, my page needs to show the new data. but the `.then(getProjects())` part of the code fetches the data without the new record, thus my page doesn't show the new row.

Comment: Ciao, let me explain better. You have your products fetched from your api. Then you add a product. At this time you already have all the info you need (pruducts + new prduct). Why ask again to server for all products? You could just add new product to products. Isn't it?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito MySQL is giving the product an id (autoincrement) and adds the owner to an own table with another new id. I need the ids in my code.

Comment: Ok and if you return the new id into the response of `addProduct`?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito This doesn't answer my original question, but yeah, that seems to be good practice. I'll give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you're right is not an answer to your question. Anyway I hope you will solve, because are 4 days that I'm thinking to a possible solution and now I feel attached  :)